# Evaluate compression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, compression

I'm researching on compression algorithms (huffman coding and LZ77) and was wondering how I would evaluate their efficiency depending on the input image. I know how they work but I can't find information on their evaluation (mathematically). Thanks!

Comment: Compression increases entropy of the input signal, which allows to increase its payload. You could try to generate source files with various entropy and compare results for Huffman and LZ77.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General-purpose (universal) compressors like LZ77 are usually compared by testing them against a standard set of sources and comparing the results, see: http://www.maximumcompression.com/, http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/summary_mf.php, for example.

Compressors for specific purposes are tested against source sets that are chosen to be as representative as possible.

For some applications it is also useful to place mathematical bounds on compression efficiency in terms of the source entropy.

Comment: Then you can't deduce thins mathematically? With probability I mean

Comment: Mathematically your average compression ratio over all inputs will be 1:1. Therefore you need to constrain these inputs somehow. Maybe you got a good math-model in mind to build synthetic data mapping to real-world needs, but as those datasets are used like Matt describes, it's probably the better way to go (with current knowledge).